# SUM WITH Left Join group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, inner-join

I have three tables which have a common column Ch_id.
I want to sum the column(total) which is there in all three tables with alias (Allocation,Received,Withdrawl,Balance).

How can I join all three tables and get result like below.

```
CH_id      Allocation   Received   Withdrawl   Balance(Received-Withdrawl)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          100000       50000       25000       25000
2          300000       20000       200000      0
3          200000       100000      0           100000

...... and so on
```

I want all the rows in CH_Allocation table

I have tried the following but it gives not so expected result.

```
SELECT
    CH_Allocation.CH_id,
    SUM(CH_Allocation.Total) AS Allocated,
    SUM(ch_funds.Total) AS received,
    (req_ch.total) AS Withdrawl
FROM CH_Allocation 
LEFT JOIN Req_CH
    ON Req_CH.CH_id = CH_Allocation.CH_id
LEFT JOIN CH_Funds
    ON CH_Funds.CH_id = CH_Allocation.CH_id
WHERE
    CH_Allocation.Project_Id = 2 AND
    Req_CH.Project_id = 2
GROUP BY
    CH_Allocation.CH_id,
    Req_CH.ch_id,
    CH_Funds.CH_id
```

and also this

```
select a.ch_id,SUM(a.total) as alloted,SUM(b.total) as received,SUM(c.total) as withdrawl,SUM(b.Total)-sum(c.Total) as balance from 
CH_Allocation a,CH_Funds b,Req_CH c
where a.CH_id=b.CH_id
and c.CH_id=b.CH_id
and b.CH_id=a.CH_id
and c.Project_id=2
and a.Project_Id=2
and b.Project_Id=2
group by a.CH_id
```

Please help experts.

Comment: Please include the structure for the other tables as well.

Comment: All the tables have these  common columns. (id,Project_id,Ch_id,Total)

Comment: You should group by only by Id... And read what group by do ^^ https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php

Comment: It was a typo and I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to this.  One is to use a `full join`, but that is rather messy because lots of `NULL` values are created.  The second is to union the tables together and then aggregate:

```
SELECT CH_id,
       SUM(Allocated) AS Allocated,
       SUM(received) AS received,
       SUM(Withdrawal) AS Withdrawal
FROM ((SELECT Project_Id, ch_id, Total as allocated, 0 as received, 0 as Withdrawal
       FROM CH_Allocation 
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT Project_Id, ch_id, 0 as allocated, Total as received, 0 as Withdrawal
       FROM Req_CH 
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT Project_Id, ch_id, 0 as allocated, 0 as received, Total as Withdrawal
       FROM CH_Funds 
      ) 
     ) t
WHERE Project_Id = 2 
GROUP BY ch_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to do this with below query.

```
    SELECT  a.CH_id AS CH_ID,isnull(t.allocated,0) AS allocated,
isnull(s.received,0) AS received,isnull(p.withdrawl,0) AS withdrawl,
isnull(received,0)-isnull(withdrawl,0) AS Balance 
FROM CH_Allocation a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  ch_id, sum(total) AS allocated FROM CH_Allocation
 where Project_Id=1 GROUP BY ch_id ) t 
 ON (a.id = t.ch_id) 
LEFT JOIN (  SELECT  ch_id, sum(total) AS received
FROM CH_Funds where Project_Id=1  GROUP BY ch_id) s ON (a.id = s.ch_id) 
LEFT JOIN (  SELECT ch_id, sum(Total) AS withdrawl  
FROM Req_CH where Project_Id=1 GROUP BY ch_id) p ON (a.id = p.ch_id)
```